# Change color of all folders in KDE Plasma

Tags: kde

How can I change the color of all folders, instead of just one, in KDE Plasma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System settings → *File Associations* → *inode* → *directory* → change icon, click *OK* and *Apply*.